# Problema com o gerar do Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Boa tarde...  estou com um problema sério, já pesquisei em foruns e grupos de whatsapp e não consegui resolver, percebi que é so no windows 10...

Vamos lá:

O meu problema é o seguinte, toda vez que instalo o Android Studio e vou criar uma nova aplicação, ele me apresenta um erro de Gradle, dizendo que não foi possivel exportar pois o arquivo esta corrompido.

======

Erro:

**Error:Failed to open zip file.
Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)**

**Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)**

**Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)**

======

Ao procurar soluçao na internet, eles falam para eu colocar o gradle manualmente, coloquei mas não soube configurar para a importação do pacote, e tals...

Uma outra solução que eu encontrei foi por o gradle na pasta gradle do propio projeto. E indo na configuração do projeto eu colocar a versao do meu gradle que no momento é 3.5-all, eu colocando isso o erro já some... Mas isto é por causa que coloquei no propio projeto, se eu criar um outro o erro vai aparecer.

segue a imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ficarei grato se alguem conseguir me ajudar, obrigado...

Comment: Você pode abrir o terminal e tentar rodar o comando "gradlew" que ele vai baixar as dependências necessárias. Normalmente é o suficiente, mas é estranho não funcionar simplesmente clicando no link exibido no erro.

Comment: eu fui no diretorio do gradle la na pasta do android e coloquei o gradle que mencionei la em cima o 3.5-all ai funcionou, sem erro mas mesmo assim estou com receio...